# Trailing Slash Issue with URL for Subdirectory

Tags: html, .htaccess, web-config, web-hosting, windows-hosting

I am currently using one host to host multiple domains (each domain is pointed to a folder in the root directory). Which generally works fine, but the problem comes when trying to access sub-directories of a domain.

So for example, I have the domain example.com which is pointed this way

example.com points to \folder\abc\

https://example.com      works fine
https://example.com/xyz/ works fine, where xyz is a sub-directory in the abc folder.
https://example.com/xyz redirects to https://example.com/folder/abc/xyz/

Is there something I need to do in my .htaccess file or web.config to fix this issue where URLs without trailing slash point in a different way?

--
Update:
This is what my .htaccess rules look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule (.+[^/])$ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear, could you please share your htaccess file's rules which are dealing with your urls in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Updated the answer with the .htaccess rules

Comment: Could you please remove line `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash` once and see if this helps you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Removed it, but no luck. Still doesn't work

Comment: Could you please restart apache and clear the cache of your browser and then try once please? Meanwhile I will try once too in my local system, let me know what you see please.